# Close Explorer window by varying ID or filename

Tags: powershell

I've been scouring these forums for hours trying to figure out a way to code something that I thought would be much more simple than this.

So here's what I'm trying to do: 
My task scheduler runs a script every two days. The script opens an `explorer.exe` path to a folder, and then deletes all of the files in that folder. The scheduler runs the script at night while I'm not in office. However, when I get into the office, the explorer window is open to that page. Trivial, I know - but i don't want to see that window open, so I want the script to run, and then close the window, so I don't see anything.

I've tried this every which way. When I try to do something simple like

```
$var1 = invoke-item C:\path\file
$var1.quit()
```

or

```
$var1.close()
```

but when I do that, I get an error message saying that the variable is null.

Then I tried stopping the process. But I don't want all explorer files to close, just that particular explorer window to close. So in order to do that, I have to know the ID of the window. But since the ID of that particular window is not static, I need to get the process ID - assign it to a variable - then use the `stop-process` cmdlet using the variable.

This is what I'm trying now:

```
get-process | where-object {$_.MainWindowTitle -eq "filename"} | select -property id | $var2
```

However, when I run this script, it's still saying that the variable is null.

So how do I assign a value to a variable? Or if anyone has a better way of closing a specific window.

(I've tried using the `stop-process` using just the `mainwindowtitle` - but it still wants an id)

Comment: Why would you automate `explorer.exe`? You can do what you're describing in a single PowerShell pipeline without ever interacting with the desktop

Comment: Why is your script opening an Explorer window in the first place? If you don't want a UI to display, don't use a UI element to do the work. Code the deletion yourself in your script, and then you won't have this issue. An Explorer window is designed to provide a **user interface** for a  **user sitting in front of the keyboard**. There is zero reason to be using one in your automated deletions via a script. This is very much an XY problem; you're fighting to solve problem Y that wouldn't exist if you'd concentrate instead on properly dealing with X.

Comment: I understand why you would think that. 

So the folder i access to delete all the files, it is constantly replenished. When i tried running the script without opening explorer - the amount of files deleted, was the same amount that was being replenished. Meaning there was no NET DECREASE of files in the folder - meaning the script would have to run all day, every day. 

The script runs the sendkeys - ctrl+all then DEL. That seems to work better, and deletes everything back to zero files more quickly, and then the amount builds back up over a few days.

Comment: If it works with GUI, it definately works directly with `Remove-Item`. If anything, GUI-automation would be slower. But without the actual script you've tried (which you would have to ask about in a new StackOverflow question), there's not much we can do to help you besides recommending to fix it. As for this question, I've already answered. :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to close a specific File Explorer window, then you would need to use `Shell.Application`. List opens file explorer windows:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$shell.Windows() | Format-Table Name, LocationName, LocationURL

Name          LocationName LocationURL           
----          ------------ -----------           
File Explorer Windows      file:///C:/Windows    
File Explorer folder       file:///C:/path/folder
```

I want to close the one in `c:\path\folde`, so lets find it and close it:

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$window = $shell.Windows() | Where-Object { $_.LocationURL -like "$(([uri]"c:\path\folder").AbsoluteUri)*" }
$window | ForEach-Object { $_.Quit() }
```

However as mentioned in the comments, you're overcomplicating this. The point of PowerShell is to automate it, which usually means you don't want to use a GUI at all. I'm not sure what you want to remove or keep etc. but here's a sample you can work with:

```
#Get contents of folder (not recursive)
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\path\folder' |
#Only files
Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
#Remove...
Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - i figured it had something to do with shell.application, but didn't know much beyond that. 

However, the way you're closing it seems like it's still closing every explorer instance/window. Is there not a way to close a specific explorer window either by using the MainWindowTitle, or by sending the process ID to a variable, and then stopping the process by variable?

Comment: Did you try it? All Windows Explorer windows runs in one explorer.exe-process (per user session/login), which means you can't kill the process. The sample above closes only the window that's inside the `c:\path\folder`-folder. You would normaly use `LocationURL` (path) or `LocationName` (title / name of folder) to find the correct window. See updated answer.

Comment: Sweet - yes that did work. Thank you. The only part of that code that I don't understand is the [uri].absoluteuri)*

Could you explain that to me? 

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Look at the table showing my file explorers, the `LocationURL`-values are URIs (`file://c:/path..`) and not filepaths (`c:\path\..`). So to convert the filepath I want to search for to the valid format (URI), I convert the filepath to an `URI`-object and get it's `AbsoluteURI`-value (full URI-path). You could use `$uri = ([uri]"c:\path\folder").AbsoluteUri` and `.. | Where-Object { $_.LocationURL -like "$uri*" }` if that makes it easier to understand. :-)

Comment: Also - does this mean that you cannot close an application (not necessarily explorer) by mainwindowtitle?

Comment: There are no `MainWindowTitle` for the window, it's not a process. However, you can use the title of the window with `LocationName`. see the table I posted above......

Comment: A short abbrevation to the PowerShell command lines above would be using $window.Quit() instead of $window | ForEach-Object { $_.Quit() }

Answer (score 1):

```
# Close specific window, when folder path contains cyrillic symbols
$folder = "D:\folder"
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$window = $shell.Windows() | Where-Object {$_.LocationURL -eq "file:///"+([uri]$folder.Replace("\","/")).OriginalString}
$window | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.Quit()}
```